# update function failed to update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to execute the update action but I keep getting the error "This specialize already exist" even though I put the name completely different. It appears that there's something wrong with my nested if in the Update action, but I used the same condition in the Create action but it works fine. I'm new to rails so forgive me if this is an obvious and stupid question. Here is my action controller code:

```
class SpecializesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_specialize, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /specializes
  def index
    @specializes = Specialize.all
  end

  # GET /specializes/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /specializes/new
  def new
    @specialize = Specialize.new
  end

  # GET /specializes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /specializes
  def create
    if(specialize_params[:name].present? && specialize_params[:specialize_category_id].present?)
      @specialize = Specialize.new(specialize_params)
      if Specialize.where(:name => @specialize.name).blank? 
        @specialize.save
        redirect_to specializes_url, notice: 'Specialize was successfully created.'
      else
        redirect_to specializes_url, notice: 'This specialize already exists.'
      end
    else
      redirect_to specializes_url, notice: 'One or more input is blank. Add failed!'
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /specializes/1
  def update
    if(specialize_params[:name].present? && specialize_params[:specialize_category_id].present?)
      if Specialize.where(:name => @specialize.name).blank?  
        @specialize.update(specialize_params)
        redirect_to specializes_url, notice: 'Specialize was successfully updated.'
      else
        redirect_to specializes_url, notice: 'This specialize already exists.'
      end
    else
      redirect_to specializes_url, notice: 'One or more input is blank. Update failed!'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /specializes/1
  def destroy
    @specialize.destroy
    redirect_to specializes_url, notice: 'Specialize was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_specialize
      @specialize = Specialize.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def specialize_params
      params.require(:specialize).permit(:name, :specialize_category_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: As the answers mention, you should ideally move this kind of validation check to the model. See [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your update method, the result of `@specialize.name is nil` from statement `if Specialize.where(:name => @specialize.name).blank?` is the reason your code always go to else block

I suggest if you do not want to use double for @specialize.name, you can use validation rule open your model specialize.rb and add below is check so name must be unique

```
validates :name, :presence => { message: 'must be present'}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false , message: 'duplicate name, please enter new name'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following things to debug this:

```
@specialize.update(specialize_params)
```

will return a boolean value which you can use to check if the validations are passing or not.

You can also do `@specilize.errors` to see if there were any errors when trying to save the record.